# PHP echo mysql field names in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this Select query:

```
$sql="SELECT * from callplandata group by description ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
                $field = mysql_fetch_field($rs);
        echo '<td>
        <input type="text" name="columnname'.$x.'" value="'.$field->name.'" />
        <input type="text" name="" value="'.$row[$i].'" />
        </td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

to display mysql table data and column names.

i use `$field->name` to show the column name but it is not showing any column names

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are all deprecated, consider upgrading to the latest `mysqli_*` or `pdo_*` functionality moving forwards.

Comment: What's `var_dump($field)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the index too

```
echo '<tr>';
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
     $field = mysql_fetch_field($rs,$i);//use the index value here
    echo '<td>
    <input type="text" name="columnname'.$x.'" value="'.$field->name.'" />
    <input type="text" name="" value="'.$row[$i].'" />
    </td>';
}
```

Comment: works great - thanks. how can i echo the number column in the for loop? i tried <input type="text" name="number'.$x.'" value="'.$row["number"].'" /> but i get an error saying Warning: Illegal string offset 'number'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `mysql_fetch_row` use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, then just loop over the row:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($sql,$conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
  foreach ($row as $column => $value) {

  }
}
```

Comment: He isn't using mysqli though. Consider explaining how to start using it.